# "Unable to get latest blockhash. " when running "anchor test"

Tags: anchor, testing

```
Unable to get latest blockhash. Test validator does not look started.
Check .anchor/test-ledger/test-ledger-log.txt for errors. Consider
increasing [test.startup_wait] in Anchor.toml.
```

This shows up whenever I try to run `anchor test` command.

Anchor.toml:

```
[features]
seeds = false
[programs.localnet]
anchor = "Fg6PaFpoGXkYsidMpWTK6W2BeZ7FEfcYkg476zPFsLnS"

[registry]
url = "https://anchor.projectserum.com"

[provider]
cluster = "localnet"
wallet = "/root/.config/solana/id.json"

[scripts]
test = "node tests/fandom.js"

[test]
startup_wait = 10000
```

I tried adding

```
[test]

startup_wait = 1000000
```

to the bottom of `Anchor.toml` but it just gets stuck on

```
Running test suite: "/mnt/c/dev/Blockchain/buildspace/darth-fandom/anchor/Anchor.toml"
```

Comment: Can you post the validator setup in `Anchor.toml?`

Comment: @yamen edited the description to add it

Comment: Have you tried running `solana-test-validator` manually? Will it start? If not, please post the output you are getting.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by deleting `target` folder and re-running `anchor test`. Error occurred due to renaming test file.

Edit: An older earlier compiled file was running instead of the new one.

Comment: Was anchor trying to run an older test?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @JacobCreech yes. It was using an earlier compiled file.